# How do I get rid of the browser's native tool tips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I'm using jQuery (1.6.4) and using a slightly modified version of [this method](http://www.queness.com/post/92/create-a-simple-cssjavascript-tooltip-with-jquery) to add a do-it-yourself tooltip to my web app.  (Basically I am dynamically generating a table, and putting up different tooltips whenever someone hovers over each cell of said table)  Once the tooltip appears my code then issues a JSON call to get more information, which it then displays in the tooltip.

```
   $('table#status_table td').live('mouseover', function() {
      // Append the tooltip template and its value
      // make it a loading graphic until we complete fetching the data
      $(this).append('<div id="tooltip"><div class="tipHeader"></div><div title="" alt="" id="tooltip_area" class="tipBody"><img src="spinner_black.gif" alt="Wait..."></div><div class="tipFooter"></div></div>');    
      // fetch data
      $.getJSON('cgi-bin/get_more_information.cgi', function(data)  {
                    var results = data.results;
                    tipBodyString = '<em>(insert results here)</em>';
                    $('#tooltip_area').html(tipBodyString);
            });
        });
```

Everything works as expected, except that Firefox displays a tooltip that echoes the HTML string I use when updating the tooltip (`tipBodyString` in the code above).  Here is a screenshot that should hopefully illustrate what I mean.

[image: Damn tooltips!]

At first I thought it was just Firefox doing this, but then I tried it in Chrome and Safari and they display these unwanted tooltips as well.

I have absolutely no idea why these tooltips are being displayed.  More importantly, is there any way to get rid of them?  I want the monopoly on tooltips to go to my app :)

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not use one of the tooltip plugins? We use one on our current project at work that is pretty good (but I forget which one, sorry). Even if you don't want to use a plugin you could have a look at how they work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `title` attribute with empty value to elements where you don't need tooltip.

Comment: OK, I feel silly now.  I did try setting an empty title attribute... but I see now that I did it in the wrong spot.  *hangs head in shame*

Comment: Spoke too soon :(  Tooltips are still there, no matter where or how often I add `title=""`.

Comment: @dburr I'd be interested to see a link, or see you recreate this. firefox only tooltips the contents of the "title" attribute

Comment: @dburr - Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: @dburr: How are you setting the title? E.g. `$('table#status_table td').title = '';` will not work. Try using [`.removeAttr('title')`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) or [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)`.title = ''`.

Comment: OK finally got to the bottom of it.  If I set a null title for my <TD> element (the one that is triggering mouseover) then no tooltips appear.  Phew!

Comment: Finally, a short answer, just like I love.